# 3D Lines cutting off partway through the screen

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-1.x

I'm making a mod where it loops through all entites and draws lines to them.

It works fine, but if an entity is out of my viewport the lines will cut off midway across the screen.

My code (for the lines, at least) is pretty much this:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3d(0,0,0);
glVertex3d(x, y, z);
glEnd();
```

x, y, and z are just the coordinates for the entities.

Not really sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Could be several things. One thing that comes in mind are the near and far clipping planes. I'm assuming you are not using any stencil or any custom clip planes.